# AWS EKS - kubectl logs [pod name]

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster running on AWS in us-east-1. I have three worker nodes running on us-east-1a, 1b, 1c respectively. All the pods running in us-east-1a allow me to login and check logs but the pods in other zones keep throwing an error:

```
Error from server: no preferred addresses found; known addresses: []
```

Any help appreciated. Basically using this setup for sharding mongodb in various zones.

Comment: What's the state of the pods that don't allow you to see logs. Can you run a `kubectl describe pod <podname>` ?

Comment: @Rico The last message says: `Normal  Started                54m   kubelet, ip-192-168-252-43.ec2.internal  Started container`

Comment: How about `kubectl get nodes`?

Comment: @Rico I can see all my three worker nodes with status ready over there and operating in different zones as listed above.

Comment: can you post the output of `kubectl -n kube-system get pods`?

Comment: @Rico `kubectl -n kube-system get pods
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aws-node-f8ssv                          1/1       Running   1          50d
aws-node-nln2l                          1/1       Running   1          50d
aws-node-pmnp6                          1/1       Running   8          50d
kube-dns-64b69465b4-52knw               3/3       Running   0          39d
kube-proxy-524ns                        1/1       Running   4          50d
kube-proxy-7mb4j                        1/1       Running   0          50d`

Comment: @ Rico Continued `kube-proxy-8h86c                        1/1       Running   0          50d
kubernetes-dashboard-7b9c7bc8c9-4bp4d   1/1       Running   0          14d
tiller-deploy-67d8b477f7-cfhdl          1/1       Running   0          28d`

Comment: Can you please add command-line flag `-v=8` and send the logs that way?

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google `I0930 21:22:57.945600   60495 loader.go:357] Config loaded from file /Users/deepan.verma/.kube/config-g3devk8scluster
I0930 21:22:57.946208   60495 loader.go:357] Config loaded from file /Users/deepan.verma/.kube/config-g3devk8scluster
I0930 21:22:57.946658   60495 loader.go:357] Config loaded from file /Users/deepan.verma/.kube/config-g3devk8scluster
I0930 21:22:57.954238   60495 round_trippers.go:383] GET https://453954E750FA10436114D6802A784A57.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/mongo-cluster-deployment-574d579cdf-jztxz`

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google `I0930 21:22:57.954255   60495 round_trippers.go:390] Request Headers:
I0930 21:22:57.954261   60495 round_trippers.go:393]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0930 21:22:57.954266   60495 round_trippers.go:393]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.10.3 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/2bba012
I0930 21:22:58.204393   60495 round_trippers.go:408] Response Status: 200 OK in 250 milliseconds
I0930 21:22:58.204461   60495 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0930 21:22:58.204482   60495 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google`I0930 21:22:58.204500   60495 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 2633
I0930 21:22:58.204519   60495 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Mon, 01 Oct 2018 01:22:57 GMT`

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google`I0930 21:22:58.204671   60495 request.go:874] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"mongo-cluster-deployment-574d579cdf-jztxz","generateName":"mongo-cluster-deployment-574d579cdf-","namespace":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/mongo-cluster-deployment-574d579cdf-jztxz","uid":"6d9f3e11-c367-11e8-b4e7-0e0ac579f624","resourceVersion":"8527198","creationTimestamp":"2018-09-28T21:42:42Z","labels":{"app":"mongo-cluster","pod-template-hash":"1308135789"},`

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google`"ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"ReplicaSet","name":"mongo-cluster-deployment-574d579cdf","uid":"38c039ca-c367-11e8-b4e7-0e0ac579f624","controller":true,"blockOwnerDeletion":true}]},"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"mongo-cluster-2a","awsElasticBlockStore":{"volumeID":"vol-0519f8ad77ad1f436","fsType":"ext4"}},{"name":"default-token-bppn5","secret":{"secretName":"default-token-bppn5","defaultMode":420}}],"containers":[{"name":"mongo-container","image":"mongo:4.0.1","args":["--dbpath","/data/db"],`

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google`"ports":[{"name":"mongo","hostPort":27017,"containerPort":270 [truncated 1609 chars]
I0930 21:22:58.246143   60495 round_trippers.go:383] GET https://453954E750FA10436114D6802A784A57.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/mongo-cluster-deployment-574d579cdf-jztxz/log
I0930 21:22:58.246171   60495 round_trippers.go:390] Request Headers:
I0930 21:22:58.246177   60495 round_trippers.go:393]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.10.3 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/2bba012I0930 21:22:58.246183   60495 round_trippers.go:393]     Accept: application/json, */*`

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google`I0930 21:22:58.267933   60495 round_trippers.go:408] Response Status: 500 Internal Server Error in 21 milliseconds
I0930 21:22:58.267952   60495 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0930 21:22:58.267978   60495 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json
I0930 21:22:58.268034   60495 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 142
I0930 21:22:58.268041   60495 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Mon, 01 Oct 2018 01:22:57 GMT I0930 21:22:58.268098   60495 request.go:874]`

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google`Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"no preferred addresses found; known addresses: []","code":500}
I0930 21:22:58.268329   60495 helpers.go:201] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no preferred addresses found; known addresses: []",
  "code": 500
}]
F0930 21:22:58.268346   60495 helpers.go:119] Error from server: no preferred addresses found; known addresses: []`

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google It seems like my pod is running successfully as you can see that I am getting a 200 response code but I am unable to log inside the pod using kubectl exec -it <pod-name> bash neither I am able to check the logs for it. Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: @Rico It seems like my pod is running successfully as you can see that I am getting a 200 response code but I am unable to log inside the pod using kubectl exec -it <pod-name> bash neither I am able to check the logs for it. 
Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

**In all workers**

1) Edit the file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

Add or update:

```
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip='private-ip-value'"
```

*For eg: `Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip=172.31.55.201"`*

2) `systemctl daemon-reload`

3) `systemctl restart kubelet`